# Add events to new nodes

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have been trying to add `click` events to a series of `divs` using a for loop. The `divs` are dynamically created and loaded. Every div is supposed to call its own callback function. But it seems every div is attached to the final event listener and calls callback function of final event listener.

Below is my basic code:

```
for(index=0; index<divs.length; index++) {
  divs[index].addEventListener("click", function(){console.log(divs[index].getAttribute("id"));}, true); //capture click event
}
```

On click only the id of final div is displayed by every div.

Comment: read about javascript closures, and edit your code. It is a variable scope problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Phil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8876163/157247) offers a good solution to the *specific* code you posted (+1), but doesn't explain what the problem was with your original code.

The problem is that the event handler closures get an *enduring reference* to the `index` variable, not a *copy* of it as of when they're created. So they all see the final value that `index` has (`divs.length`). For instance, this code

```
for (index = 0; index < 4; ++index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(index);
    }, 100);
}
```

...will log "4" four times when the timeouts occur, not "0", "1", "2", and "3".

To correct it in the general case where you want to make sure your handler closes over a specific value, use a factory function that generates the event handler function for you, where the event handler closes over the argument you feed the factory function instead of the loop variable:

```
for(index=0; index<divs.length; index++) {
    divs[index].addEventListener("click", createHandler(divs[index], true); //capture click event
}

function createHandler(div) {
    return function(){
        console.log(div.getAttribute("id"));
    };
}
```

There, the event handler closes over `div`, which doesn't change.

Closures are one of the most powerful features of JavaScript. Once you understand how they work (and they're actually a lot simpler than people think), you can use them to really good effect. More: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: +1 for the great problem description. Your `createHandler` method would also work in IE's (< 9) `attachEvent` whereas mine would not (`this` support is broken)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder closure is interesting, thanx

Answer (score 3):

This is because you're using `divs[index]` in the event handler which, after the loop has completed, is set to the last element.

Use `this` instead. Also, you can use the one event handler instead of creating a bunch of identical closures, eg

```
function logId(e) {
    console.log(this.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

... and in your loop ...

```
divs[index].addEventListener("click", logId, false);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Memory_issues

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `this` keyword as pointed out by @phil.

But, to explain what your problem was, consider this closure:

```
for(index=0; index<divs.length; index++) {
  (function(index){
      divs[index].addEventListener("click", function(){
          console.log(divs[index].getAttribute("id"));
      }, true);
  })(index);
}
```

Now, every function get's its own copy of the `index` variable. In your code, they all share the same variable; so in the end, `index` would be equals to `divs.length -1` regardless of which `div` is actually being clicked.

Comment: your illustration works as well, but i still don't understand what (function(arg){ statements })(arg) is, thanx for your help