# Assign click handler in for loop in Javascript

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, hover

Can anyone tell me why this works:

```
$("#test1 td").click(function(event) {
  $("#test1").addClass("tableRowSelected");
});
$("#test2 td").click(function(event) {
  $("#test2").addClass("tableRowSelected");
});
```

But this doesn't:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
  $("#test" + i + " td").click(function(event) {
    $("#test" + i).addClass("tableRowSelected");
  });
}
```

I've also tried using `i.toString()` in the second code snippet but this doesn't help :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign click handlers in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091765/assign-click-handlers-in-for-loop)

Comment: Sorry - I didn't see that, I think that answer is good for me though thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handler function receives an *enduring reference* to the `i` variable, not a copy of it as of when it was created. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876144/add-events-to-new-nodes/8876173#8876173) for details.

Comment: This place will get kind-of lonely once some genius builds smarts into a popular IDE to explain this to people.

Comment: The answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091765/assign-click-handlers-in-for-loop you suggested did it thanks.

Comment: @ing0: Good deal. I think I'll add an explanation to that answer at some point, it's pretty lacking at present but that title seems like it should come up on searches a lot.

Comment: I checked a few answers but didn't see that one. I think I foolishly thought it was something not-so common. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

What about using:

```
$("table").on("click", "td", function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("tableRowSelected");
});
```

This will use event delegation to attach the event to the table and filter click events by td

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

To get it to work, change `$("#test" + i).addClass("tableRowSelected");` to `$(this).parents('tr').addClass("tableRowSelected");`

As Pointy pointed out, actually i does exist with a value of 4 which is invalid.

---

That's because, in the second case, when the event actually gets fired, `i` no longer exists.

Comment: @Pointy - +1 yes, got it wrong! actually i does exist with a value of 4 which is invalid